# Display subcategory only if someone selects a category

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any suggestion on how I can display or show the subcategory only when someone selects a category and also if someone chose a category and does not select a subcategory(for example person selects the option "select sub-category"), it will automatically hide the subcategory select box.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<!-- Row for Main Category Starts-->
<div class="row required">
<label for="category_level_1">Category</label>           o              
<div class="column">
    <select id="Category" >
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    <?php
    $getCategory = $category->getAllCat();
    if($getCategory){
    while($result = $getCategory->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result['catId']; ?>"><?php echo $result['catName']; ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
    </select>                          
</div>
</div><!-- Row for Main Category Ends-->
<!-- Row for Sub Category Starts-->
    <div class="row hidden"  >
    <label for="subcategory">Subcategory</label>                           
    <div class="column">
    <select id="Subcategory" >
    <option value="">Select sub-category</option>
    </select>                            
</div>
</div>
 <!-- Row for Sub Category Ends-->
```

And here is my Ajax and Javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Category').on('change',function(){
    var categoryID = $(this).val();
    if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'fetch.php',
            data:'catId='+categoryID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Subcategory').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Subcategory').html('<option value="">Select Category first</option>');
    }
}); 
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: Whay happens when you run this code?

Comment: The code works fine. But wanted suggestion on how to hide the subcategory and  show it only when the user selects a category. In this code both category and subcategory are visible. But I just want the category to be shown. and the subcategory to be shown only if a user selects a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `#Subcategory` loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Subcategory').parent().parent().hide();
```

Then in this part of your JS:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'fetch.php',
  data: 'catId=' + categoryID,
  success: function (html) {
    $('#Subcategory').html(html).parent().parent().show();
  }
});
```

and your else statement can hide it again if you want.

---

OP added in comments

> a user selects category one and selects "select sub-category" as subcategory instead of one, it will hide the subcategory automatically

Here's your event listener:

```
$('#Subcategory').change(function () {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
  }
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Subcategory').parent().parent().hide();
$('#Subcategory').change(function () {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
  }
});
$('#Category').on('change',function(){
    var categoryID = $(this).val();
    if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'fetch.php',
            data:'catId='+categoryID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Subcategory').html(html).parent().parent().show();
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Subcategory').html('<option value="">Select Category first</option>');
    }
}); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a minute of your time to help. The code is alright. But what I mean is, how to hide the subcategory and show it only when the user selects a category. In your code both category and subcategory are visible. But I just want the category to be shown. and the subcategory to be shown only if a user selects a category

Comment: Yeah, that's totally it. Sorry I couldn't properly formulate the problem in a comprehensive way. And also, if for example, a user selects category one and the subcategory displays, and he selects "select sub-category" as subcategory instead of one, it will hide the subcategory automatically.

Comment: Thanks. But is it not the Category that loads instead of the subcategory?

Comment: I haven't quite understood what you just modify. Please, can you demonstrate?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it. But I don't exactly know how to structure the complete ajax and javascript  using your code

Comment: @JPDouglas What do you mean?

Comment: I mean can you please show the complete script with your code included? I'm totally new to JS and Ajax.

Comment: Yeah. Now it is ok. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is working fine and you just want to just hide subcategory use following

```
$('.column').css('display',”none”);
```

in the `else` part of your jquery after you fill `SubCategory`

And do

```
$('.column').css('display',”block”)
```

in your AJAX `if` block

You are technically hiding `div` having `subcategory` and not the actual control

> Note: Its better to use some unique id for div instead of class name for accessing in jquery. So instead of $('.column'), use $('#ID_OF_Div').

Comment: Using a class selector like that is risky, it's going to make all column-class elements disappear. Better to use unique selectors.

Comment: Yes. This is just suggestion according to html shown. I will edit answer